# Postgres: query planner not respecting table inheritance constraint when querying for null

Tags: postgresql, optimization, execution-plan, postgresql-9.3

I'm having an issue with slow queries that is caused by the planner checking every inherited table instead of only the one with the constraint.

I have a table with 0 rows called "search_result". This table has a few inherited tables with different constraints based on the "polarization", where all our data resides. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE search_result_positive
(
  CONSTRAINT search_result_positive_polarization_check CHECK (polarization = (1))
)
INHERITS (search_result);

CREATE TABLE search_result_negative
(
  CONSTRAINT search_result_negative_polarization_check CHECK (polarization = (-1))
)
INHERITS (search_result);

CREATE TABLE search_result_unpolarized
(
  CONSTRAINT search_result_unpolarized_polarization_check CHECK (polarization IS NULL)
)
INHERITS (search_result);
```

When I execute a query using "WHERE polarization = 1", for example, the query planner will show that it has only checked the "search_result_positive": table, which is the desired behavior.

However, when the query is "WHERE polarization IS NULL", it'll check every single table, taking an immense amount of time. Here's an example for "search_result_positive":

```
SELECT  "search_result".* FROM "search_result"  WHERE (polarization = 1)  ORDER BY published_on DESC LIMIT 20;

Limit  (cost=0.44..17.65 rows=20 width=2027) (actual time=3.638..3.666 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  Merge Append  (cost=0.44..249453.67 rows=289872 width=2027) (actual time=3.637..3.663 rows=20 loops=1)
        Sort Key: search_result.published_on DESC
        ->  Sort  (cost=0.01..0.02 rows=1 width=2882) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
              Sort Key: search_result.published_on DESC
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              ->  Seq Scan on search_result  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=2882) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Filter: (polarization = 1)
        ->  Index Scan Backward using ix_search_result_positive_published_on_asc on search_result_positive  (cost=0.42..245830.25 rows=289871 width=2027) (actual time=3.633..3.658 rows=20 loops=1)
              Filter: (polarization = 1)
Planning time: 2.640 ms
Execution time: 3.762 ms
```

And now, this is what happens when we query for null:

```
SELECT  "search_result".* FROM "search_result"  WHERE (polarization IS NULL)  ORDER BY published_on DESC LIMIT 20;

Limit  (cost=1.93..143.83 rows=20 width=1758) (actual time=205790.210..206266.419 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  Merge Append  (cost=1.93..462744.74 rows=65221 width=1758) (actual time=205790.208..206266.403 rows=20 loops=1)
        Sort Key: search_result.published_on DESC
        ->  Sort  (cost=0.01..0.02 rows=1 width=2882) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
              Sort Key: search_result.published_on DESC
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              ->  Seq Scan on search_result  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=2882) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Filter: (polarization IS NULL)
        ->  Index Scan using ix_search_result_hybrid_published_on_desc on search_result_hybrid  (cost=0.14..44.44 rows=1 width=2882) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (polarization IS NULL)
        ->  Index Scan Backward using ix_search_result_negative_published_on_asc on search_result_negative  (cost=0.42..126163.49 rows=1 width=2039) (actual time=44646.431..44646.431 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (polarization IS NULL)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 174428
        ->  Index Scan Backward using ix_search_result_neutral_published_on_asc on search_result_neutral  (cost=0.42..53749.59 rows=1 width=1996) (actual time=29539.393..29539.393 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (polarization IS NULL)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 115678
        ->  Index Scan using ix_search_result_no_apply_published_on_desc on search_result_no_apply  (cost=0.14..44.44 rows=1 width=2882) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (polarization IS NULL)
        ->  Index Scan Backward using ix_search_result_positive_published_on_asc on search_result_positive  (cost=0.42..245105.57 rows=1 width=2027) (actual time=131590.509..131590.509 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (polarization IS NULL)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 295475
        ->  Index Scan using ix_search_result_unpolarized_published_on_desc on search_result_unpolarized  (cost=0.29..35643.06 rows=65215 width=1758) (actual time=13.863..490.048 rows=20 loops=1)
              Filter: (polarization IS NULL)
Planning time: 1.197 ms
Execution time: 206266.593 ms
```

This is driving me crazy. I don't understand why every table is being checked instead of only "search_result_unpolarized". This is driving me crazy already. The only other choice I have for this is to rewrite part of our system to query only a specific table instead of letting Postgres decide, which will be a fair amount of work. There must be a better way. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

We're using Postgres 9.3.19 on Amazon RDS

Comment: Is this supposed to work in PG 9.3?

Comment: Also, 9.3 is very old. Strongly recommend upgrading to 10.

Comment: I think that is a limitation of the old inheritance based partitioning.

Comment: I agree, we need to update. I just checked, we have a different database with the same schema on 9.6, same problem occurs. However, what confuses me is why it works with polarization = 1 but not polarization is null

Comment: I know it is nearly 1 year but PostgreSQL scan all child  tables because you have null values on them.
You need to add one more constaint that `check (polarization is not null)` but first you need to move null values out of child tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraint exclusion has some caveats.  This very case (that non-NULL-ness is not considered, even when the existing check implicates it) is not listed in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-CONSTRAINT-EXCLUSION), but it's still there in later versions, too.  The solution is to add another check that explicitly excludes NULLs:

```
ALTER TABLE search_result_positive ADD CHECK (polarization IS NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE search_result_negative ADD CHECK (polarization IS NOT NULL);
```